# How to get regex of URL that does not have a word as a token?

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I match an URL that matches all of these conditions:

- the domain is *example.com*, but subdomain is not *blog.example.com*
- the first URL token is not *"news"* or *"archives"* or *"blog"*  (ie `example.com/FIRST_URL_TOKEN`)
- none of the subsequent URL tokens is *"blog"* (ie `example.com/FIRST_URL_TOKEN/SUBSEQUENT_URL_TOKEN/SUBSEQUENT_URL_TOKEN`)

So:

`http://example.com/test` should match

`http://blog.example.com/test` should not match

`http://example.com/test/blog/test` should not match

`http://example.com/test/test2` should match

Here is what I have so far:

```
regex = /^http(s)?:\/\/(?!blog\.$)example.com(\.\w+)?\/(?!news$|archive$|blog$).*/
```

However, I'm missing something as `http://example.com/test/blog/test` should not match.

Comment: Why does this have to use a regex? Break down the URL using the URI module, and look at its individual parts. It'll be more easily maintained. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: It doesn't have to be a regex, but it sure will make it easier to maintain, and less code to write. I simply have to add this regex to my already long list of regex's. With your method, I'd have to write another function, and 100+ more functions if I encounter 100 more cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%r{^https?://[^/]*(?<!blog\.)example\.com/(?!news/|archives/|blog/)(?!.*/blog(/|$)).*}
```

[See it in action](http://rubular.com/r/X8OCNlkAE9)

---

There were quite some problems with your original regex. Mainly, `$` doesn't mean what I think you means and you were not excluding `blog/`.

So here is a breakdown:

- There is an alternative syntax for creating regexes `%r{}`, use it if you are going to escape *forward slashes* a lot
- `^` -from the start
- `https?//` - *http//* or *https//*
- `[^/]*` - multiple characters, which are not *forward slash*es
- `(?<!blog\.)` - negative lookbehind to ensure the subdomain was not *blog.example.com*
- `example\.com` - the *example.com* domain itself
- `/(?!news/|archives/|blog/)` - after first slash, the *"url token"* is not *news* or *archives* or *blog*
- `(?!.*/blog(/|$))` - any of the further *"url tokens"* are not *blog*
- `.*` - match the remaining characters

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a complex regex, which will usually grow even more complex and difficult to manage over time, I'd recommend writing a simple method that breaks the test down into smaller parts, and returns a true/false whether the URL is valid/usable.

```
require 'uri'

def match_uri(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)

  if uri.host != 'example.com' ||
    uri.path[%r!^/(?:news|archives|blog)/!i] ||
    uri.path[%r!/blog/!i]
    return false
  end

  true
end


# 'http://example.com/test' should match
match_uri('http://example.com/test') # => true

# 'http://blog.example.com/test' should not match
match_uri('http://blog.example.com/test') # => false

# 'http://example.com/test/blog/test' should not match
match_uri('http://example.com/test/blog/test') # => false

# 'http://example.com/test/test2' should match
match_uri('http://example.com/test/test2') # => true
```

Here's what URI is returning:

```
uri = URI.parse('http://example.com/path/to/file')
uri.host # => "example.com"
uri.path # => "/path/to/file"
```

The only problem I see with the logic you're using, is a "path/to/file" could actually be "path/to/blog.ext" which would cause the logic to break. If that's possible, using:

```
File.dirname(uri.path) # => "/path/to"
```

will strip the filename off so the test only looks at the true path, not the path and file:

```
def match_uri(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)

  uri_dir = File.dirname(uri.path)

  if uri.host != 'example.com' ||
    uri_dir[%r!^/(?:news|archives|blog)!i] ||
    uri_dir[%r!/blog!i]
    return false
  end

  true
end
```

"[Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)" is a good read.

Comment: Thanks but actually this would make less easy to maintain, not easier. This is because I already have a list of regular expressions to check against, and if I make this a regular expression, I don't need to write more code to handle 1 more case. So everything is more elegant.